# Maintain highest and lowest values only in Y axis of d3.js Bar graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i was using the d3.js v4 for making bar graph . i just want only the highest and lowest values as ticks in bar graph

[image]

The above graph shows several ticks for given data. it should be only 0 and 7 printed on yaxis removing other values.

Also how can we maintain the data value on each bar.

below is the d3.js code being used

```
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 70, left: 40}



var data =[
  {
     "Type_Miss":"High",
     "Value_Miss":"5"
  },
  {
     "Type_Miss":"Medium",
     "Value_Miss":"1"
  },
  {
     "Type_Miss":"Ignore",
     "Value_Miss":"2"
  },
   {
     "Type_Miss":"High",
     "Value_Miss":"4"
  },
   {
     "Type_Miss":"High",
     "Value_Miss":"7"
  },
   {
     "Type_Miss":"High",
     "Value_Miss":"1"
  },
   {
     "Type_Miss":"High",
     "Value_Miss":"3"
  }];

    var width = 650 - margin.left - margin.right
    var height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var height1 = 400-margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var svg = d3.select("#bardiv").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right+60)
    .attr("height", height1 + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", 
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
          .data([data]) ;


    var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.1),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);


    var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


      x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Type_Miss; }));
      y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.Value_Miss; })]);



      g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
      .selectAll("text")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("dx", "-.8em")
      .attr("dy", "-.55em")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" );


      g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", "0.71em")
       .attr("dx","0.81em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "end");



      g.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("rect")
          .attr("class", "bar")
          .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.Type_Miss); })
          .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.Value_Miss); })
          .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
          .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.Value_Miss); });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to show only the minimum and the maximum ticks, you can simply use the domain as a getter...

```
y.domain()
```

...to set the ticks in the `tickValues` function. Check this demo:

```js
  var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 70,
    left: 40
  };

  var data = [{
    "Type_Miss": "High",
    "Value_Miss": "5"
  }, {
    "Type_Miss": "Medium",
    "Value_Miss": "1"
  }, {
    "Type_Miss": "Ignore",
    "Value_Miss": "2"
  }, {
    "Type_Miss": "High",
    "Value_Miss": "4"
  }, {
    "Type_Miss": "High",
    "Value_Miss": "7"
  }, {
    "Type_Miss": "High",
    "Value_Miss": "1"
  }, {
    "Type_Miss": "High",
    "Value_Miss": "3"
  }];

  var width = 650 - margin.left - margin.right
  var height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var height1 = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right + 60)
    .attr("height", height1 + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
      "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .data([data]);


  var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.1),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);


  var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


  x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.Type_Miss;
  }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.Value_Miss;
  })]);

  g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
    .selectAll("text")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("dx", "-.8em")
    .attr("dy", "-.55em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)");


  g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickValues(y.domain()))
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", "0.71em")
    .attr("dx", "0.81em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "end");

  g.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return x(d.Type_Miss);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(d.Value_Miss);
    })
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return height - y(d.Value_Miss);
    });
```

```html
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

As an additional information, if you want to show the minimum and the maximum **in the data**, excluding the zero baseline, just use `d3.min` and `d3.max`:

```
.tickValues([d3.min(data, d => d.Value_Miss), d3.max(data, d => d.Value_Miss)])
```

Here is the demo:

```js
  var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 70,
    left: 40
  };

  var data = [{
    "Type_Miss": "High",
    "Value_Miss": "5"
  }, {
    "Type_Miss": "Medium",
    "Value_Miss": "1"
  }, {
    "Type_Miss": "Ignore",
    "Value_Miss": "2"
  }, {
    "Type_Miss": "High",
    "Value_Miss": "4"
  }, {
    "Type_Miss": "High",
    "Value_Miss": "7"
  }, {
    "Type_Miss": "High",
    "Value_Miss": "1"
  }, {
    "Type_Miss": "High",
    "Value_Miss": "3"
  }];

  var width = 650 - margin.left - margin.right
  var height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var height1 = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right + 60)
    .attr("height", height1 + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
      "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .data([data]);


  var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.1),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);


  var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


  x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.Type_Miss;
  }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.Value_Miss;
  })]);



  g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
    .selectAll("text")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("dx", "-.8em")
    .attr("dy", "-.55em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)");


  g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickValues([d3.min(data, d=>d.Value_Miss),d3.max(data, d=>d.Value_Miss)]))
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", "0.71em")
    .attr("dx", "0.81em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "end");

  g.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return x(d.Type_Miss);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(d.Value_Miss);
    })
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return height - y(d.Value_Miss);
    });
```

```html
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: it works.How can we maintain the values on each bar  ? the Value_Miss as in this data .

Comment: What do you mean by "how can we maintain the values on each bar"?

Comment: i mean printing values on each bar as we are removing the tick marks on the y axis. Value_Miss as in data for each bar.

Comment: That's a *different* problem. If you have a different problem, please post *another* question.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use `.tickValues()` on your y-axis to explicitly define the tick values. Right now, I have directly added `0` and `7` but you can calculate that outside based on your data.

We can do it like the following when we are appending our `y-axis`:

```
   g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickValues([0, 7]))
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", "0.71em")
       .attr("dx","0.81em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "end");
```

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/fbus9062/